# Java String/Integer wont resolve into enum

Tags: java, enums, constructor

I have following enum in java

```
public enum TypeSignsEnum {

    NEGATIVE("45","17","11","66","31","56","85","14","15","91","30"),
    POSITIVE("58","26","97","12","89","18","22","19","20","16","25","92","10","14","24","60","65","79","57","27","23","96"),
    DEFAULT();

    TypeSignsEnum(String ...values) {
        List<String> values1 = Arrays.asList(values);
    }

}
```

There is multiple input values for each ( also for default, but not yet )
and all the following logic will depend on this..

However, this will always result in error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
```

or in case i try to use actual `Integers`

```
No enum constant com.xxx.zzz.yyy.model.TypeSignsEnum.11
```

( 11 is third from left, Negative enum... )

Same code but with `Integers`

```
public enum TypeSignsEnum {

    NEGATIVE(45, 17, 11, 66, 31, 56, 85, 14, 15, 91, 30),
    POSITIVE(58, 26, 97, 12, 89, 18, 22, 19, 20, 16, 25, 92, 10, 14, 24, 60, 65, 79, 57, 27, 23, 96),
    DEFAULT();

    TransactionTypeSignsEnum(Integer ...values) {
        List<Integer> values1 = Arrays.asList(values);
    }

}
```

How do i make this work?

The point is other class calling `valueOf(value)` which should be either NEGATIVE or POSITIVE, but currently every value is error

Comment: What are you trying to do? know if 11 is POSITIVE or NEGATIVE?

Comment: The constructor has to be `TypeSignsEnum`, not `TransactionTypeSignsEnum`. Also, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to solvey you use case is to:

- store the values in a private field (enums in Java are not simple constants, they can have fields and methods)
- add a public static method to search for your enum value

```
public enum TypeSignsEnum {

    NEGATIVE(45, 17, 11, 66, 31, 56, 85, 14, 15, 91, 30),
    POSITIVE(58, 26, 97, 12, 89, 18, 22, 19, 20, 16, 25, 92, 10, 14, 24, 60, 65, 79, 57, 27, 23, 96),
    DEFAULT();

    private final HashSet<Integer> values;

    TypeSignsEnum(Integer ...values) {
        this.values = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(values));
    }

    public static TypeSignsEnum fromValue(int value) {
        for (TypeSignsEnum e : TypeSignsEnum.values()) {
            if (e.values.contains(value)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return DEFAULT;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(TypeSignsEnum.fromValue(11));
```

Answer (score 0):

`11` is not a value of `TypeSignsEnum`.

`TypeSignsEnum` only has 3 values, `POSITIVE`, `NEGATIVE` and `DEFAULT`

What you need an auxiliary method to return the enum containing the value you look for:

```
enum TypeSignsEnum {

    NEGATIVE("45","17","11","66","31","56","85","14","15","91","30"),
    POSITIVE("58","26","97","12","89","18","22","19","20","16","25","92","10","14","24","60","65","79","57","27","23","96"),
    DEFAULT();

    private List<String> enumValues;

    TypeSignsEnum(String ...enumValues) {
        this.enumValues = Arrays.asList(enumValues);
    }

    public static TypeSignsEnum findByValue(String val) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(e -> e.enumValues.contains(val))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(DEFAULT);
    }

}
```

I renamed your list to `enumValues` so you don't get confused with the `values()` method that lists all the enums

```
TypeSignsEnum typeSignsEnumFor11 = TypeSignsEnum.findByValue("11");
System.out.println("typeSignsEnumFor11 = " + typeSignsEnumFor11);
```

> typeSignsEnumFor11 = NEGATIVE